# Find first occurrence of value by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset with two columns: Name and Date. The names are repeating with different dates. I am trying to get a list of unique names and the date when that name first time occurred.

Here is the sample of data:

```
    Name    Date
0   Smith   2021-01-02
1   Johnson 2021-01-03
2   Williams    2021-01-04
3   Brown   2021-01-05
4   Jones   2021-01-06
5   Garcia  2021-01-07
6   Miller  2021-01-08
7   Davis   2021-01-09
8   Rodriguez   2020-01-10
9   Martinez    2018-01-11
10  Smith   2021-01-12
11  Johnson 2017-01-13
12  Williams    2016-01-24
13  Brown   2011-12-15
14  Jones   2009-01-16
15  Garcia  2008-11-17
16  Miller  2021-02-18
17  Davis   2004-03-09
18  Rodriguez   2001-01-20
19  Martinez    2002-01-21
20  Smith   2010-05-22
21  Johnson 2011-12-23
22  Williams    2006-01-04
23  Brown   2006-01-25
24  Jones   2014-01-04
25  Garcia  2013-01-13
26  Miller  2021-01-28
27  Davis   2021-01-29
28  Rodriguez   2021-01-30
29  Martinez    2021-01-31
```

I tried using pandas groupby function, but I am not getting correct results:

```
    #Sample Data
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("SampleData2.xlsx")
df["first_test"] = df.groupby("Name")["Date"].transform("first")
df
```

I get export like this:

```
    Name    Date    first_test
0   Smith   2021-01-02  2021-01-02
1   Johnson 2021-01-03  2021-01-03
2   Williams    2021-01-04  2021-01-04
3   Brown   2021-01-05  2021-01-05
4   Jones   2021-01-06  2021-01-06
5   Garcia  2021-01-07  2021-01-07
6   Miller  2021-01-08  2021-01-08
7   Davis   2021-01-09  2021-01-09
8   Rodriguez   2020-01-10  2020-01-10
9   Martinez    2018-01-11  2018-01-11
10  Smith   2021-01-12  2021-01-02
11  Johnson 2017-01-13  2021-01-03
12  Williams    2016-01-24  2021-01-04
13  Brown   2011-12-15  2021-01-05
14  Jones   2009-01-16  2021-01-06
15  Garcia  2008-11-17  2021-01-07
16  Miller  2021-02-18  2021-01-08
17  Davis   2004-03-09  2021-01-09
18  Rodriguez   2001-01-20  2020-01-10
19  Martinez    2002-01-21  2018-01-11
20  Smith   2010-05-22  2021-01-02
21  Johnson 2011-12-23  2021-01-03
22  Williams    2006-01-04  2021-01-04
23  Brown   2006-01-25  2021-01-05
24  Jones   2014-01-04  2021-01-06
25  Garcia  2013-01-13  2021-01-07
26  Miller  2021-01-28  2021-01-08
27  Davis   2021-01-29  2021-01-09
28  Rodriguez   2021-01-30  2020-01-10
29  Martinez    2021-01-31  2018-01-11
```

However, what I am trying to get is:

```
Name    FirstDate
Smith   5/22/2010
Johnson 12/23/2011
Williams    1/4/2006
Brown   1/25/2006
Jones   1/16/2009
Garcia  11/17/2008
Miller  1/8/2021
Davis   3/9/2004
Rodriguez   1/20/2001
Martinez    1/21/2002
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by name, and then take the minimum date. Something like this:

```
df.groupby('Name').agg({'Date': 'min'})
```

With `df` like you provided, I find:

```
                 Date
Name                 
Brown      2006-01-25
Davis      2004-03-09
Garcia     2008-11-17
Johnson    2011-12-23
Jones      2009-01-16
Martinez   2002-01-21
Miller     2021-01-08
Rodriguez  2001-01-20
Smith      2010-05-22
Williams   2006-01-04
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling `transform`, drop duplicates on `Name` and newly added column.

```py
out=(df.assign(first=df.groupby("Name")["Date"].transform("first"))
    .drop_duplicates(['Name',  'first'])
    .drop(columns='first'))

        Name        Date
0      Smith  2021-01-02
1    Johnson  2021-01-03
2   Williams  2021-01-04
3      Brown  2021-01-05
4      Jones  2021-01-06
5     Garcia  2021-01-07
6     Miller  2021-01-08
7      Davis  2021-01-09
8  Rodriguez  2020-01-10
9   Martinez  2018-01-11
```

Comment: ThePyGuy -  the out you provided is not correct. If you take a look these dates they are not correct. For example, Smith first time occurred 5/22/2010, Johnson 12/13/2011...